# Check for variable in string

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

I have string of names divided by `|`:

|akong|adelyn|ahchong|peter|john

Then I want to insert new name `ahchong` How can I check if there is already that name in string and not allow to insert it?

What I tried. I have a string:

```
var listOfElements = $(this).closest(".procLeader").find("ol").text();
var trim_listOfElements = listOfElements.replace(/ /g, '');
```

And current name which is draggable element:

```
var current_name = ui.draggable.text();
var trim_current_name = $.trim(current_name);
var substr_current_name = (trim_current_name).substr(2);
```

I tried `indexOf()` to check if name is in string:

```
if (trim_listOfElements.indexOf(substr_current_name) >= 0){
  $('.test2').html('IN STRING');
} else {
  $('.test2').html('NOT IN STRING');
}
```

I do everything inside drop function, here is full function:

```
$(function(){
  var itm = [];  
  $(".procLeader ol").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer', 
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui){
      var current_name = ui.draggable.text();
      var new_array_name = itm.includes(current_name);
      if (new_array_name === false) {
          $(this).find(".placeholder").empty();//remove text inside placeholder
          $(this).find(".placeholder").css('height', '20px');//change height of placeholder class
          var item = ui.draggable;
        if (!ui.draggable.closest('.placeholder').length){
          item = item.clone().draggable();// if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
          item.addClass('droppedItem').appendTo(this);// append item to placeholder
          $(".droppedItem").draggable({ disabled: true });

          var listOfElements = $(this).closest(".procLeader").find("ol").text();
          var trim_listOfElements = listOfElements.replace(/ /g, '');

          var trim_current_name = $.trim(current_name);
          var substr_current_name = (trim_current_name).substr(2);

          $(".test").val(trim_listOfElements);
          if (trim_listOfElements.indexOf(substr_current_name) >= 0){
            $('.test2').html('IN STRING');
          } else {
            $('.test2').html('NOT IN STRING');
          }   
        }        
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

How can I check if variable in string and dont add it there?

### EDIT

Here What I tried. I changed string to an array:

```
      var newarr =  trim_listOfElements.split('|');
      newarr.shift();//remove fisrt empty element
```

And tried to check using `inArray()`:

```
      if($.inArray(substr_current_name, newarr) !== -1) {
        $('.test2').html('IN ARRAY');
      } else {
        $('.test2').html('NOT IN ARRAY');
      }
```

Full function now:

```
$(".procLeader ol").droppable({
  tolerance: 'pointer', 
  hoverClass: 'highlight',
  drop: function(ev, ui){
    var current_name = ui.draggable.text();
    var new_array_name = itm.includes(current_name);
    if (new_array_name === false) {
        $(this).find(".placeholder").empty();//remove text inside placeholder
        $(this).find(".placeholder").css('height', '20px');//change height of placeholder class
        var item = ui.draggable;
      if (!ui.draggable.closest('.placeholder').length){
        item = item.clone().draggable();// if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
        item.addClass('droppedItem').appendTo(this);// append item to placeholder
        $(".droppedItem").draggable({ disabled: true });

        var listOfElements = $(this).closest(".procLeader").find("ol").text();
        var trim_listOfElements = listOfElements.replace(/ /g, '');

        var trim_current_name = $.trim(current_name);
        var substr_current_name = (trim_current_name).substr(2);

        var newarr =  trim_listOfElements.split('|');
        newarr.shift();//remove fisrt empty element

        if($.inArray(substr_current_name, newarr) !== -1) {
          $('.test2').html('IN ARRAY');
        } else {
          $('.test2').html('NOT IN ARRAY');
        }
      }      
    }  
  }
});
```

Now it shows `NOT IN ARRAY` for every name i dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `indexOf`, I've seen it used in this exact way, return false positives and cause a bug.

Instead use

```
$.inArray(substr_current_name, trim_listOfElements.split('|'))
```

Comment: In what case do you see false positive. I have been using indexOf for years, but I have never had any issues. Let me know so I can look out for it.

Comment: @juminoz the options in my case were something like `apple and orange|orange` now suddenly search for `apple` returns true even though it's a value not necessarily a valid value.

Comment: please see edited question. I tried an array but it shows not in array every time I add name even if this name is already in an array

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy have you tried debugging to see what's in the array? Are you familiar with the `debugger` command?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich That's valid results so Javascript is working properly, just not for the case where array is stored as string with separator.

Comment: @juminoz maybe I misunderstood you. I wasn't saying javascript is broken :) just that it could cause logic issues.